# Select link by text (exact match) and replace href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please demonstrate for me how to implement this filter jquery into the below scenario i have. As i want it to find the link that contains exactly the word "products"

```
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Products"; });
```

Note the code below changes BOTH links, not just the first

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a:contains('Products')").attr('href', '/category/All-Products')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Products</a> 
<a href="#">My Products</a>
```

Comment: Not able to get what issue you are facing here. Could you please elaborate it more. Thanks!

Comment: I made you a snippet to have a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the selector by the filter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === "Products"; 
  }).attr('href', '/category/All-Products')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Products</a> 
<a href="#">My Products</a>
```

Comment: $( "a" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $( "Products", this ).length === 1;
  })
    .attr('href', '/category/All-Products');

Comment: @LDS that would select `<a href="#"><Products>A</Products></a>` not `<a href="#">Products</a>`